# Problem converting a string to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my input showing only one row (data type string). The other rows will have different kind of values.

row 1 =
'---\nid: 4\c_id: 2555\ndescription: \ncity: \ncreated_at: 2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z\nupdated_at: 2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z\ndeleted_at: \ncharge: 0'

rows 2 =
'---\nid: 686\c_id: 2058\ndescription: \ncity: \ncreated_at: 2017-05-12 05:14:22.946269000 Z\nupdated_at: 2017-06-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z\ndeleted_at: \ncharge: 2'

So I have tried doing this. Assuming df is the dataframe name.

```
def splitting(df):
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df['object'].iloc[i] is None:
            df['cleaned_object'].iloc[i] = df['object'].iloc[i]
        else:
            elements = df['object'][i].split('\n')[1:]
            clean_elements = []
            for element in elements:
                if ':' not in element:
                    clean_elements[-1] = clean_elements[-1] + element
                else:
                    clean_elements.append(element)
                    
            data = {}
            
            for element in clean_elements:
                element = element.split(': ')
                data[element[0]] = element[1]
                
            df['cleaned_object'] = json.dumps(data)
    return df
```

which will ideally produce something like this.

row 1 = '{"id": "4", "c_id": "2555", "description": "''", "city": "''", "created_at": "2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000", "updated_at": "2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z", "deleted_at": "", "charge": "0"}'

row 2 = '{"id": "686", "c_id": "2508", "description": "''", "city": "''", "created_at": "2017-05-12 05:14:22.946269000 Z", "updated_at": "2017-06-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z", "deleted_at": "", "charge": "2"}'

but instead, I'm getting every row the same thing

row 1 = '{"id": "4", "c_id": "2555", "description": "''", "city": "''", "created_at": "2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000", "updated_at": "2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z", "deleted_at": "", "charge": "0"}'

row 2 = '{"id": "4", "c_id": "2555", "description": "''", "city": "''", "created_at": "2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000", "updated_at": "2017-05-12 05:04:22.946269000 Z", "deleted_at": "", "charge": "0"}'

May I know where and what am I doing wrong? Or if you can show me how is it done. That will be great. Thanks in advance!

To clarify, row 1 indicates df['object'][i], and row 2 is df['object'][i+1]

Comment: I assume you have `\nc_id`, and not `\c_id`? (I also assume you have `row1 =...`, not `row 1 =...`. Please make sure the code you post accurately represents your code. If I am right, then your strings are valid [tag:yaml], and you should probably use a YAML parser like `pyyaml` and just write `yaml.load(row1)` to get your dictionary. In general, for standard formats, existing tools are almost always more convenient, faster and safe than a home-brewed solution.

Comment: row 1 indicates df['object'][0]. sorry for not stating